# echo array from sql in option select

Tags: php

I want echo array in select option :

[image: Click here to see]

like this shape :

```html
structure i want 
for 
aaaa
<select>
<option>4<option>
<option>7<option>
<option>1<option>
</select>
```

```
aaaa  
4

7

1  
bbbb

1

 9

 10

 12

 13
```

Comment: What are you displaying here? What have you tried and what issue are you encountering?

Comment: i want like this shape from mysql

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You just want a list of characters? Add your code.

Comment: i want display this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwSRn.jpg  as 
aaa   4  7  1      bbbb  1 9 10 12 13

Comment: your description is not clear, can you make an effort and explain better?

Comment: You want to split `no_ana` on the commas? This it not a well written question. Please correct it.

Comment: can you make a html with the structure you want?

Comment: for aaa<select><option>4<option/><option>7</option><option>1</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to extract the data from the database, so you need to use the SQL query in the PHP function `mysqli_query()`:

`$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT no_ana FROM tablename WHERE name='aaaaa'");`

where `$conn` is your connection set in the `mysqli_connect()` function.

To retrieve the data:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data = $row['no_ana'];
}`

The variable `$data` is now your string of data. You have separated the individual pieces of data by commas, so to put each into an array as you have suggested we can use the `explode()` function as such:

`$array = explode(',', $data);`

Now your data is in the array `$array`.

To create the option tags we can then do the following in a loop:

`$options = "";
foreach($array as $arraydata){
        $options = $options . "<option>" . $arraydata . "</option>";
}`

Now your options are constructed.

We just put it in the HTML `<select>` tags now:

`$html = "<select>" . $options . "</select>";`

Last thing to do is simply: `echo $html;`

You can use the same for any other row, such as "bbbb".